# Are there any beings from Norse Mythology that could be mistaken for a Kitsune (fox-person spirit)?

Tags: norse, comparative, japanese, animals

I'm starting a new Roleplaying campaign soon, and my character is norse/icelandic themed.

One of the other character is inspired by Kitsune.

I want to find out what, if anything, might my character mistake this character for?

I've done some limited research, and it seems like either Fylgja or Hamingja ..? But I'm not clear if that's just because I've misread the wikipedia pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A huldra

[Huldra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulder) (Norway) or "[skogsrå](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skogsr%C3%A5)" (Sweden) are creatures from folklore who mostly look like young, friendly human women, but have something that marks them as inhuman: a back that is "hollow" or covered with bark, hooves, or a tail, sometimes a fox-tail. They lived in forest. In some stories, they tried to seduce lonely men who then could either disappear or lose their soul, unless they noticed the tail or back, or they could act as protectors of animals. Other stories depicted them as grateful and helpful if treated with respect.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Fylgia and Hamingja, the fox is a sacred animal to the goddess [Sigyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigyn). She's the wife of Loki, the trickster god.

Comment: Do you have any source on that? I find this a bit hard to believe, considering how little is said about Sigyn in the Norse corpus.